# Как отловить клик вне области элемента jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, ajax-load

Допустим при клике на текст вызывается функция которая позволяет редактировать блок текста, как при клике вне этого блока вызвать другую функцию для отправки изменений на сервер?

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.target.classList.contains('class') ? func1() : func2;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так: выдал бы каждому такому редактируемому блоку атрибут, скажем, `data-editable` с уникальным значением - рандомной строкой или индексом каким. Всем блокам с этим атрибутом выдал бы обработчик клика, который бы среди прочего записывал в глобальную переменную тот самый идентификатор из юзер-атрибута. При любом клике проверять наличие в `event.target:data-ediatble` нашего записанного ключа. Если он есть - игнор, если нет - отправка значения и отключение режима редактирования.

```js
let nowEdittingBlockKey = '';

const startEdit = () => {
  if (nowEdittingBlockKey) return false;
  event.target.classList.add('editable__editMode');
  nowEdittingBlockKey = event.target.getAttribute('data-editable');
  document.addEventListener('click', endEdit);
}
const endEdit = (event) => {
  if (event.target.getAttribute('data-editable') === nowEdittingBlockKey) return false;
  document.querySelector(`[data-editable=${nowEdittingBlockKey}]`).classList.remove('editable__editMode');
  nowEdittingBlockKey = '';
  document.removeEventListener('click', endEdit);
}
const loadPage = () => {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-editable]')].forEach(editable=>{
    editable.addEventListener('click', startEdit);
  });
}
```

```css
#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.editable {
  margin-top: 2em;
  width: 25%;
  height: 40vh;
  transition: box-shadow .5s ease-in-out;
}
.editable__editMode {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em green;
}
```

```html
<body onload=loadPage()>
  <div id='content'>
    <textarea data-editable='asfdihn' class='editable'></textarea>
    <textarea data-editable='asfsdxvhn' class='editable'></textarea>
    <textarea data-editable='acbvdren' class='editable'></textarea>
  </div>
</body>
```